# Create a pie wedge shaped CALayer object

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

Here is an attempt to create a `CALayer` object that's a section of a circle. With the following I'm getting a circle. However, is there a way to specify `startAngle` and an `endAngle` to define a wedge-shaped CALayer which will be used for animating?

```
import UIKit

Class Pie: CALayer {

init(radius : CGFloat,
     position : CGPoint) {

    super.init()

    self.radius = radius
    self.position = position

    self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
    self.cornerRadius = radius 
}
```

The above code currently creates a circle. To add to the above, I would like to create a slice  shape. Thank you.

Comment: The obvious class to start with is `CAShapeLayer`. Create it, then add it to the layer hierarchy where you want.

Comment: Use UIBezierPath.addArc

Comment: @ElTomato thank you. it worked for me!